# During layout View.getChildAt(i) returns null even when view at that position should exist

Tags: android, android-layout

I get NPEs where all the code executed is only framework code. Maybe somebody could give me any leads as to what to watch for in my code? And during which activity's lifecycle stage this framework code is run?

This happens quite a long time after app's start, so maybe here an app is being recreated and view is being restored?

**FrameLayout:**

```
@Override
protected void onLayout(boolean changed, int left, int top, int right, int bottom) {
    final int count = getChildCount();

    // ...

    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        final View child = getChildAt(i);

        // NPE happens at this line
        if (child.getVisibility() != GONE) {
            final LayoutParams lp = (LayoutParams) child.getLayoutParams();

            final int width = child.getMeasuredWidth();
            final int height = child.getMeasuredHeight();

            // ...

            child.layout(childLeft, childTop, childLeft + width, childTop + height);
        }
    }
}
```

**Stacktrace:**

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:400)
    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14842)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4601)
    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:448)
    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14842)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4601)
    at android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout.onLayout(DrawerLayout.java:887)
    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14842)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4601)
    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:448)
    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14842)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4601)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1669)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1527)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1440)
    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14842)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4601)
    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:448)
    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14842)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4601)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performLayout(ViewRootImpl.java:2206)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:2020)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1230)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:5093)
    at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:791)
    at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:591)
    at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:561)
    at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:777)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5283)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1102)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:869)
    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

**Main layout:**

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <!-- Fragment container, may hold various fragments -->
    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

    <!-- Fragment container -->
    <!-- Fragment's top view is TabHost which is descendant from FrameLayout -->
    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/navigation_drawer"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/navigation_drawer_width"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="left"/>

    <!-- Fragment container -->
    <!-- Fragment's top view is TabHost which is descendant from FrameLayout -->
    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/personal_drawer"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/personal_drawer_width"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="right"/>

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Edit:

Another idea - one of my fragments that get's placed in `@+id/personal_drawer` has following `onDestroyView()` override:

```
@Override public void onDestroyView() {
    for (ProductList v : tabsContent) {
        if (v != null) {
            v.tearDown();
        }
    }
    tabsContent = null;
    tabHost = null;
    super.onDestroyView();
}
```

May this be a problem?

Comment: Can you show more of your `Adapter`?

Comment: I don't know which view is being shown here nor whether that's a `ListView`. That's the problem, if I'd know which of my views causes NPEs that'd be halfway to fixing them

Comment: It's a `FrameLayout` in a `FrameLayout` in your `DrawerLayout`. Possibly a fragment container.

Comment: I know that fragment's view gets wrapped in `DecorView`, don't know if that's relevant here though. So indeed, first `FrameLayout` under `DrawerLayout` is fragment container, but the second - is it root of Fragment's view?

Comment: Ah, and I've added XML for activity's layout - that which defines `DrawerLayout`

Comment: What are the `ProductList` in `tabsContent` and what does `tearDown()` do?

Comment: `ProductList` is a `FrameLayout`, has a `ListView` and couple of other views inside. `tearDown()` merely unsubscribes from RxJava Observables